# Links instances of links across multiple site collections

Tags: content-deployment, expiration

We are looking at de-commissioning a site within our collection, however prior to doing the de-commission, I'm wanting to generate a report of pages that contain links to the specific pages within the site collection.

What would be some solutions that wouldn't involve a Farm Admin?